# Xamarin Blank Screen

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to explore Xamarin, trying to create simple CURD project.

I was able to make some progress by watching youtube video's, but I am not sure what went wrong all of the sudden I am getting blank screen in my emulator when I am trying to deploy the project.

Firstly it showed me error stating

> 'the targetFrameWorkVersion is greater than my project version. You
>   need to increase the version for the project'.

I tried it, I increased my project version. This issue got resolved but gave birth new error.

Secondly

> 'To deploy this application, your deployment target should be running
>   Windows Universal Runtime version 10.0.16299.0 or higher. You
>   currently are running version 10.0.14393.2007. Please update your OS,
>   or change your deployment target to a device with the appropriate
>   version.'

I looked up for newer version of OS, but it seems my OS is already up to date.

I really appreciate if anyone help me out with tips or clue.

Environment is as follows

- Visual Studio: 2017
- Operating System: Windows 10

I am attaching ScreenShot of error

[image: Error]:

[image: Target Version]

[image: Emulator Manager]

[image: SDK]

Comment: that error is in your UWP project.  If you are only trying to get Android to work you can ignore it

Comment: @Jason: I am sorry Jason, I couldn't get you. Can you please say more about it. Thanks.

Comment: What @Jason is saying, is that the error you're getting refers to your UWP project, not the Android. If you unload UWP project and then hit F5 (or whatever you're doing to run android app) then the error will go away. Nevertheless, you could just change your UWP target versions [this doc might help](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/version-adaptive-apps#configure-your-visual-studio-project), to what the error says and that way the error will go away as well.

Comment: @Ale_lipa: that didn't help. I unloaded UWP project and tried, I change the target version from Project - Properties but still blank screen. Yes the first error of updating OS is gone, but I am still getting those 3 warnings. Thanks for your Doc, learned something from there.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

Set your android project as `StartUp` project
In your VS menu go to `Build ->Configuration Manager`
Uncheck the UWP project from both Build and Deploy, i hope your issue will be sorted.

Answer (score 0):

**first**

its not your SDK, this is cause by old nugets in your project.
update all your nugets. at least xamarin.forms.dll

**second**
update your windows OS to latest. then
install appropriate microsft windows mobile sdk version. the link should appear when you right click your project and select install missing features

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/updates-and-versions/choose-a-uwp-version

Comment: Thanks for tip, but it didn't help. I updated nuget, but couldn't solve the issue. Error still exists.